# How to create a sorting algorithm for this special array with linear time?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I've got a tricky question I can't seem to figure out.
We have an array which its length is n+m.

The array is made out of n numbers that are sorted, then m numbers that are sorted. for example:

```
2 5 8 11 15 17 19 3 4 9 10
```

then n=7 and m=4.

I need to sort the whole array completely in `O(n)` timewise and not usage of extra arrays / lists.

Comment: I got a tricky question for you: in which language should this *question* be solved: Java or C#? Pick one, not both.

Comment: It actually does not really matter, C# for my case but I need to understand the algorithm, I can convert it from any language. @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: so you want to *merge* two sorted arrays, hint, hint. It's called a merge sort (or at least the last stage of one). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

Comment: By the way, it seems like a *special* case of [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort).

Comment: do you by chance need it to be sorted in less than O(n*lg(n)) time?

Comment: So what is your question?  This isn't a site for doing your homework for you. What code have you written so far? Do you have a question about that code?  Can you solve a simpler problem?  Suppose that M and N are both 2; can you **write a program** that solves the problem then?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza and I changed it, it needs to be O(n) and no usage of extra arrays.

Comment: It's still the last stage of a merge sort, the O(1) memory limit just makes it more complicated.

Comment: Ok, now you got an answerable question here. Still, looks more like a question for code golf rather than for this site. In order to keep it on topic here, you should at least shown what have you tried to solve it, we won't solve your homework directly.

Comment: try searching for "O(n) array sort" in your favorite search engine. Not sure the values of `m` and `n` are relevant, since the items can overlap.

Comment: @RufusL seems that you haven't understood the problem. Also, the common linear sort algorithms assume things on the data and use additional data structures to accomplish the sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform the last stage of merge sort where you merge two sorted lists/arrays.  The added complication is that you want O(1) memory usage.  This can be done as follows.

If you have an arrays of size `n + m`

- start with an array `i` [0 .. n) and `j` [n .. n+m)
- if the first array is lower, leave it.
- if the second array is lower, swap it with the second array.
- now the first array is in two places [n..j) [i..m)

In short you have three arrays

- [0..i+j) - the sorted portion.
- [n..j) [i+j..n) the first array
- [j..n+m) the second array.

as you progress `i+j` you get to the end in one pass and have a sorted array.

Comment: I'm not going to upvote this answer, because I came to the same solution, but decided to refrain from posting an answer until the OP gave some sort of attempt

Comment: @SamIam true, although this pseudo code leaves a bit to the imagination. +1

Comment: Unless the OP didn't post their question right, they are stating that they have one array.  That array has "n" sorted values.  After the last "n" value, there are "m" sorted values.

Comment: @BogdanBanciu He's not using extra arrays.  He's using 1 array, which he breaks up into 3(or 4, depending on how you want to think about itit) logical sections.  He's just referring to these sections as "arrays"

Comment: @Shar1er80 there is one array that contains two blocks of data sorted separatedly and that are contiguous. You can think of this as two *logical* arrays inside one real array.

Comment: There is three logical/notional arrays inside one original array; the two arrays you are merging and the one you are placing sorted entries into.